# Rails: undefined method `id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Each User has_many :notices, and each Notice has_many :comments, each of class Notice. Each Notice/Comment has_one :supernotice, the notice upon which the comment is being made.
I get this error message upon attempted submission of a comment: `undefined method 'id' for "#<Notice:0x0000010eed6958>":String`. Why does Rails think my `Notice` is a `String`?

notices_controller.rb:

```
def create
  @notice = user.notices.build(notice_params)
  if @notice.save
    if !params[:notice][:commentee].nil?
      @notice.create_comment(params[:notice][:commentee])
    end
  end
end

private
  def notice_params
    params.require(:notice).permit(:content, :comentee)
  end
```

notice.rb:

```
belongs_to :user
has_one :active_comment_relationship, class_name: "Commentrelationship", foreign_key: "commenter_id", dependent: :destroy
has_one :supernotice, through: :active_comment_relationship, source: :commentee

def create_comment(other_notice)
  active_comment_relationship.create(commentee_id: other_notice.id)
end
```

To submit a comment on a notice in _notice.html.erb:

```
  <%= form_tag( {controller: "notices", action: "create"}, method: "post", id: "comment_form" ) do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :callsign, @user.callsign %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "notice[commentee]", notice %>
    <%= text_area_tag "notice[content]", '', id: "commentField" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Reply" %>
  <% end %>
```

Server logs:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "callsign"=>"bazzer", "notice"=>{"commentee"=>"#<Notice:0x00000110a49140>", "content"=>"Hello there."}, "commit"=>"Reply"}
```

Comment: You cannot pass object in params `<%= hidden_field_tag "notice[commentee]", notice %>`  ,  `"commentee"=>"#<Notice:0x00000110a49140>"`, it becomes string.

Answer (score 0):

Because it can only be rendered in a form value as a string. Serializing it back and forth won't do you any good either. The obvious option would be passing in the `id` of that notice and look it up. But I personally prefer a bit different practice.

You may not need to pass the `notice_id` from the form at all if the comment is posted on that notice's `show` page: `:id` is already part of the route there. If you make a nested resource:

```
resources :notices do
  resources :comments
end
```

...your comments' routes stick right on top of notices' routes. You can make a controller for the comments, and a collection of comments could be accessed with routes like:

```
notices_comments_path(@notice)
# => /notices/42/comments
```

So when you post a comment to the URL of the above format, you have to pass in **no hidden params at all**:

- *Commentee* can be looked up from the given `params[:note_id]` in the route
- `callsign` can be looked up on `current_user` at controller layer (with either Devise or Sorcery)

And the reason to do all this is because the **hidden inputs are hidden from sight, but not from developer tools and are as such open for tampering**. To counter that, it's tempting to use additional checks in the controller, but why do that if he controller is able to assign them by itself?

**Antipattern warning:** don't nest resources too much. 2 levels are okay, 3 levels are concerning, 4 levels are terrible.